# Prove that there exists integers such that a, x, y, b is part of an arithmetic series and a, x_0, y_0, b is part of a geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

a, x, y, b, x_0, y_0 must all be integers.

My work:

One way its possible is if d = 0 (difference) and r = 1 (ratio is 1). 
If a = x1 = x2 = y1 = y2 = b, then its possible.

Another solution comes from the following:

a + 3d = b <- Arithmetic Series (Closed Form)
a + r^3 = b <- Geoemtric Series (Closed Form)

Therefore a + 3d = ar^3 => 1 + 3d/a = r^3 => d = a(r^3 - 1)/3
Plugging in values for a and r, we can get a few more options.
Example: a = 9, r = 2, d => 21, which works since,
a = 9, x = 30, y = 51, b = 72 and a = 9, x_0 = 18, y_0 = 36, b = 72.

Know that I know it exists, I'm having trouble proving its possible.
What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: You already have! If you've found an example, then the general case is possible.

Comment: Is there a more formal way to prove it? Through contradiction, a contrapositive proof, etc..?

Comment: Idk, you could write something like $(a,b)=(r,r^4)$ and $(x_0,y_0)=(r^2,r^3)$. Then it's just a matter of choosing $R=(r^4-r)/3$ to be an integer, which can be done for $r\equiv 0,1$ mod $3$, in which case you let $x=r+R$, $y=r+2R$.

Comment: Thank you, that's sort of what I was looking for.